# response status 0 with Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: web-services, extjs, sencha-touch

i want to call a web service with AJAX, i used this code:
Code:

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'http://localhost:4305/Service/test',
     success : function(response) {
     Ext.getCmp('res').setValue(response.responseText);
     var user = eval('('+ response.responseText+ ')'); 
    if(user !== "null") {
    Ext.Msg.alert("Bienvenue Monsieur",user);
    Ext.getCmp('res').setValue(response.status);
  }
   else {Ext.Msg.alert("Mot de passe ou login incorrecte","veuillez reeseyer");}
     },
     failure: function(response) {
  Ext.getCmp('res').setValue(response.status);
    }
    });
```

it's work when i tested it in my browser (chrome), but it's return a 0 as status code when i tested it on an ANdroid Emulator. what shall i modify my code.

Comment: where exactly do you see status 0?

Answer (score 0):

The status is the HTTP status code (like 404 for page not found, 500 for server error, etc). I assume that the Android emulator would probably not send back a meaningful HTTP status code.  Have you looked at `response.responseText` in the failure callback?  You might need to debug your service directly to see what's going on.

Comment: thank you sha and bmoeskau, response.responseText in the failure function don't give any thing :( im using sencha touch 1 to make mobil app, when i test my app on MoSync IDE (Android Emulator) i saw this response status and it's not invok the url

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your url.calling any service from localhost may be blocked by android emulator because emulator itself run on local host.Host your service on other system and then try to call it.